# Getting "error while generating package metadata" when installing TkFontAwesome

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm trying to install [TkFontAwesome](https://github.com/israel-dryer/TkFontAwesome) using python -m pip install tkfontawesome, but always get the following error:

```
Collecting tkfontawesome
  Using cached tkfontawesome-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (405 kB)
Collecting tksvg==0.7.4
  Using cached tksvg-0.7.4.tar.gz (50 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Installing dependency cmake... Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2krbeh5s\tksvg_7491a69795da43779e9e71e527849349\setup.py", line 62, in <module>
          sp.call(["pacman", "--needed", "--noconfirm", "-S", "mingw-w64-x86_64-{}".format(dep)])  # , stdout=sp.PIPE)
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\subprocess.py", line 339, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
          restore_signals, start_new_session)
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
          startupinfo)
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Never had any problems installing packages using pip before. The file subprocess.py IS in \Thonny\lib\ if this WinError 2 means that.

I'm using:

- Python 3.7.7
- pip 22.0.3
- Tk 8.6.9
- Thonny 3.2.7
- Windows 10

So far i've tried:

- to update my pip and setuptools (they're already up-to-date)
- to install TkFontAwesome using ez_setup
- to install TkFontAwesome using --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures

No use. Anyone have any ideas what to do next? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this after your pip3 install package:

```
    --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures
```

eg, if you want:

```
    pip3 install imageAI
```

then:

```
    pip3 install imageAI --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures
```

copy from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70916814/error-metadata-generation-failed-cant-install-artic-module).

Comment: `option --use-deprecated: invalid choice: 'backtrack-on-build-failures' (choose from 'legacy-resolver')`