# getting for some packages exit code: 1

Tags: python

For the code I wrote I need some packages, I trying to download some packages to my computer, but some just don't work. I'm trying to download for example pip install matplotlib==2.0.2

I get an error message:

```
pip install matplotlib==2.0.2
Collecting matplotlib==2.0.2
  Using cached matplotlib-2.0.2.tar.gz (53.9 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [63 lines of output]
      ============================================================================
      Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

      BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                  matplotlib: yes [2.0.2]
                      python: yes [3.9.2 (tags/v3.9.2:1a79785, Feb 19 2021,
                              13:44:55) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]]
                    platform: yes [win32]

      REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                       numpy: yes [version 1.23.4]
                         six: yes [using six version 1.15.0]
                    dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.8.2]
                 functools32: yes [Not required]
                subprocess32: yes [Not required]
                        pytz: yes [using pytz version 2021.1]
                      cycler: yes [using cycler version 0.10.0]
                     tornado: yes [using tornado version 6.1]
                   pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.4.7]
                      libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                              be found. Using local copy.]
                    freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype (ft2build.h)
                              could not be found.  You may need to install the
                              development package.]
                         png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                              found.  You may need to install the development
                              package.]
                       qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                              found. Using local copy.]

      OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
                 sample_data: yes [installing]
                    toolkits: yes [installing]
                       tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
              toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

      OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                      macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                      qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                      qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
                     gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
                   gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                      gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                              Tk]
                       wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                         gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                         agg: yes [installing]
                       cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
                   windowing: yes [installing]

      OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                      dvipng: no
                 ghostscript: no
                       latex: no
                     pdftops: no

      OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                        dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

      ============================================================================
                              * The following required packages can not be built:
                              * freetype, png
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I update my pip:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied:
```

But my pip is up to date, I'm using python 3.9.2, I can't figure out what the problem is, it seems everything is fine, but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: try another version of matplotlib. It happens that libraries are broken. Especially newer versions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: "metadata generation failed", can't install Artic Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70916814/error-metadata-generation-failed-cant-install-artic-module)

Comment: There is a clear message of what you need "The following required packages can not be built: freetype, png"