# Error while trying to install Jupyter on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter, thonny

I'm trying to install Jupyter for Python, but I'm having this problem while installing. This is happening with other packages when I try to install them through pip as well. Not sure how to solve it. Can somebody help me out here?
Note: I've installed Python through Thonny.

```
C:\Users\bhati\hello\Tkinter>pip install jupyter
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ustomtkinter (c:\users\bhati\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ustomtkinter (c:\users\bhati\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages)
Collecting jupyter
  Using cached jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.7 kB)
Collecting nbconvert
  Downloading nbconvert-7.2.8-py3-none-any.whl (274 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 274.8/274.8 kB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting ipykernel
  Using cached ipykernel-6.16.2-py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting jupyter-console
  Using cached jupyter_console-6.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting ipywidgets
  Using cached ipywidgets-8.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (137 kB)
Collecting qtconsole
  Using cached qtconsole-5.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
Collecting notebook
  Using cached notebook-6.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (439 kB)
Collecting matplotlib-inline>=0.1
  Using cached matplotlib_inline-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl (9.4 kB)
Collecting ipython>=7.23.1
  Using cached ipython-7.34.0-py3-none-any.whl (793 kB)
Collecting tornado>=6.1
  Using cached tornado-6.2-cp37-abi3-win32.whl (424 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\bhati\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter) (21.3)
Collecting traitlets>=5.1.0
  Using cached traitlets-5.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (116 kB)
Collecting nest-asyncio
  Using cached nest_asyncio-1.5.6-py3-none-any.whl (5.2 kB)
Collecting debugpy>=1.0
  Using cached debugpy-1.6.5-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (4.8 MB)
Collecting pyzmq>=17
  Using cached pyzmq-25.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (866 kB)
Collecting jupyter-client>=6.1.12
  Using cached jupyter_client-7.4.9-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting psutil
  Using cached psutil-5.9.4-cp36-abi3-win32.whl (247 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab-widgets~=3.0
  Using cached jupyterlab_widgets-3.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (384 kB)
Collecting widgetsnbextension~=4.0
  Using cached widgetsnbextension-4.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\bhati\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-console->jupyter) (2.11.2)
Collecting prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.36-py3-none-any.whl (386 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\bhati\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (4.8.2)
Collecting mistune<3,>=2.0.3
  Using cached mistune-2.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting bleach
  Using cached bleach-5.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (160 kB)
Collecting markupsafe>=2.0
  Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (14 kB)
Collecting nbformat>=5.1
  Using cached nbformat-5.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Collecting jupyter-core>=4.7
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
Collecting defusedxml
  Using cached defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting tinycss2
  Using cached tinycss2-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=3.6 in c:\users\bhati\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (4.11.1)
Collecting nbclient>=0.5.0
  Using cached nbclient-0.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1
  Using cached pandocfilters-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.7 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab-pygments
  Using cached jupyterlab_pygments-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting jinja2>=3.0
  Using cached Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting argon2-cffi
  Using cached argon2_cffi-21.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting Send2Trash>=1.8.0
  Using cached Send2Trash-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting prometheus-client
  Using cached prometheus_client-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Collecting nbclassic>=0.4.7
  Using cached nbclassic-0.4.8-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 MB)
Collecting terminado>=0.8.3
  Using cached terminado-0.17.1-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting ipython-genutils
  Using cached ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting qtpy>=2.0.1
  Using cached QtPy-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\bhati\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=3.6->nbconvert->jupyter) (3.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.4 in c:\users\bhati\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=3.6->nbconvert->jupyter) (4.3.0)
Collecting jedi>=0.16
  Using cached jedi-0.18.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\users\bhati\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter) (4.4.2)
Collecting pickleshare
  Using cached pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
Collecting backcall
  Using cached backcall-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in c:\users\bhati\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter) (65.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\bhati\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in c:\users\bhati\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=6.1.12->ipykernel->jupyter) (2.8.2)
Collecting entrypoints
  Using cached entrypoints-0.4-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
Collecting pywin32>=1.0
  Using cached pywin32-305-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (11.1 MB)
Collecting jupyter-server>=1.8
  Using cached jupyter_server-1.23.5-py3-none-any.whl (346 kB)
Collecting notebook-shim>=0.1.0
  Using cached notebook_shim-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting jsonschema>=2.6
  Using cached jsonschema-4.17.3-py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
Collecting fastjsonschema
  Using cached fastjsonschema-2.16.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting wcwidth
  Downloading wcwidth-0.2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pywinpty>=1.1.0
  Using cached pywinpty-2.0.10.tar.gz (26 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]

      Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
      This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
      the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/

      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ustomtkinter (c:\users\bhati\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ustomtkinter (c:\users\bhati\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ustomtkinter (c:\users\bhati\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages)
```

I've tried upgrading pip to the latest version

Comment: I am also facing the same problem using the 'Special Virtual Environment' option in Thonny.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by installing the latest version of Thonny and consecutively Python.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70931808/15144104).
Its offer is to add the following to the installation command:

```
--use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures
```

So you should use the following command to install Jupyter:

```
pip install jupyter --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures
```